# Calling a Javascript variable inside an html tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags

My Javascript goes something like this:

```
if (choice=="green") {
    var choicecolor="#00"+num+"00"
}
...
```

And I need to access the variable 'choicecolor' inside an html tag. This was my failed attempt:

```
<div id="box" style="background-color: "choicecolor>...</div>
```

How can I properly put the variable inside the tag?

Comment: It seems your brain tends to see two way bindings as a natural function, start using frameworks like angular, knockout, ember etc and you can use the same variable names (kinda) inside the html templates and they will always be in sync

Comment: not sure why you are changing the backgroundColor but maybe changing the element class might be a better idea http://stackoverflow.com/q/195951/1959948

Comment: `Element.style.backgroundColor = '#0f0';` You don't put JavaScript variables into HTML, you just affect the DOM with it, unless you're using `document.write()` which is not recommended. `Element.style.cssText = 'background-color:#0f0;`  will overwrite the entire HTML `style` attribute, which I also don't recommend. Probably really want to use `Element.className = 'choicecolor';` and just have your CSS set up already. `Element` could be `document.getElementById('box')` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Use the DOM API to set it. Make sure the element exists first.

```
document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = choicecolor;
```

Or you could use a templating engine, but that is more problematic.